# Topmost 'fixed' position div moving with non position div

Tags: css, html, css-position

Consider the following code:

```css
div {
    width:100%;
    height:64px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

.top-fixed {
    position:fixed;
}

.middle-fixed {
    position:fixed;
    top:64px;
}

.bottom {
    margin-top:128px; #64+64
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div class="top-fixed">Top Fixed</div>
        <div class="middle-fixed">Middle Fixed</div>
        <div class="bottom">Bottom</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

For div.bottom, I am using margin-top property so that it does not overlap with the top-most div. But it also brings div.top-fixed 'down' with itself (see the fiddle).

How can I rectify it? One way is possibly using padding-top property for div.bottom instead of margin-top, but that does not sound elegant.

Comment: Here's a similar question that answers WHY: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38679945/why-do-non-positioned-non-child-divs-move-fixed-headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the CSS of the your .bottom element to:

```
.bottom {
    position:relative;
    top:128px; #64+64
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You missed top 0 in the top-fixed div.

Try this

```
.top-fixed {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `top:0;` to your .top-fixed class.